# Mongodb server stop automatically

Tags: php, mongodb

My api has tremendous requests and stores this data to mongodb.

MongoDb server stops automatically.

And get the following error.

```
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection closed calling ismaster on 'localhost:27017']
```

Sometimes it stopped after 12 midnight, And i need to restart it again.

Comment: make a cron that auto checks whether its running or not if not then restart

Comment: but why it happens daily

Comment: You will tell us check log why it shutdown... no. of request doesn't matter there must be something else

Comment: serverStatus was very slow saying in mongodb log file

Comment: at every 12:06 AM

Comment: serverStatus slow means your server was sluggish and the most common reason is,  a very slow disk. I am pretty much sure that your disk is not able to perform well enough to handle the number of requests you get.

Comment: Thank you!  @AbhayPS i have increased space on server. Will check it tomorrow

Comment: adding space will not make the disk faster. You need to find a solution to have more IO per second possible.

Comment: As this happens for mongodb. Is any mongodb configuration for this to better IO operations